# how to stop the cursor from jumping to new line in textarea

Tags: jquery

I have been stuck with a very simple problem but don't know the solution.My question is how to stop the cursor from jumping to new line in textarea on pressing the enter key. I want to happen nothing with the cursor inside the textarea on clicking the enter key.

I have googled it for a long time and also got some suggestions on stackoverlfow but didn't solve my problem.

My code is :

```
$(function(){

$('#test').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            e.preventDefault();
        }       
    });
 })
```

where test is the id of the textarea. Somebody help me please. I will be greatly thankful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to prevent the cursor from jumping to next line in textarea using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935913/how-to-prevent-the-cursor-from-jumping-to-next-line-in-textarea-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#test').keydown(function(e){
    return e.which !== 13;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KLtvs/).

The reason for using `keydown` (instead of `keyup`) is that this captures the event before the character is added to the value in the `textarea`, basically `keyup` captures 'too late' to work.

The `return e.which !== 13` basically returns `false` if the <kbd>enter</kbd> button is pressed, otherwise allows the key-value to be entered (returning `true`).

Comment: thanks, that also works. but what do you think how to implement this in tinymce editor ??

Comment: What do you mean 'that also works'? Both answers are (now...) identical. As for 'how to implement this in [TinyMCE] editor'? I have no idea, it's a tool I've never used, I'm afraid. Given that wasn't the question you asked, I'd suggest researching (use Google and search to see if previous questions have been asked covering this), and perhaps asking a question to specifically address that problem.

Answer (score 1):

keyup is too late, use keypress:

```
$('#test').keydown(function(e){
    return e.which !== 13;
 });
```

Comment: Isn't the `keydown` trigger at first ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera, does it matter?

Comment: No, but if it's the first candidate then why not use it, just asking.

Comment: @gdoron Thanks brother that worked for me in textarea. But can I use this in TinyMCE editor ?

Comment: @user2702406, now is the right time to mention that little detail... I don't know, never used that library.

Comment: No, that *allows* the enter key to create a new-line; you'd need (as in my own answer) `return e.which !== 13;`

Comment: It ([TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api3:event.tinymce.editor.onkeydown)) could be found here.

Comment: @gdoron
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
        tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getDoc(), 'keypress', function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode==13){
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert('enter was pressed');
   }
        });
      });
 }
This is the configuration for the tinymce, it works well but preventdefault function does not work here.

Comment: @user2702406: why not test it, and find out for yourself? I, similarly, have never used TinyMCE, but assuming it works, or is compatible, with jQuery I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @gdoron 
when i press enter key , alert works but not preventdefault.